# How to add custom attributes to each timeslot cell in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Is there any way to add a new attribute to each timeslot for time grid in Fullcalendar v4?

Something similar to **eventRender**, where i can set attributes for each event rendered like this

```
eventRender: function(info) {
 info.el.setAttribute("r-params", "resourceId=10");
}
```

I didn't manage to find any cell element function in the doc, the closest i found is "**info.dayEl**" object but it's for whole day.

In other words, I want to change this:

```
<tr data-time="10:00:00">...</tr>
<tr data-time="10:15:00">...</tr>
```

To this with my own attribute:

```
<tr data-time="10:00:00" t-params="t=10:00:00&resourceId=2">...</tr>
<tr data-time="10:15:00" t-params="t=10:15:00&resourceId=2">...</tr>
```

Comment: First question...why do you need to add a resource ID to the timeslot? If you're using the Scheduler the way it's intended you should already be able to see which resource a timeslot belongs to.

Comment: Anyway, if you take a look at the rendered HTML for any particular view you'll see that the effect of a timeslot is actually created from two tables overlaid on top of each other. So there is no single HTML table cell which represents a single timeslot, unfortunately. You'll see one for each time, but not a specific time/day or time/resource combo. Depends what you actually need it for.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the reply. I am building this Scheduler plugin on top of an existing backend system. One of the backend javascript detect clicks on elements with t-params for example, which the script will takes in the time and resourceId for further processing. I can't edit the backend js.

Comment: well you should be able to use a CSS selector (and [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) to detect all rows which have a `data-time` attribute, and set a t-params attribute on each one as well.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, I solved the problem. Your suggestion gave me an direction. I used dateClick() to first generate a new element containing the time and resourceId, then i simulate a click on this new element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do changes your event html like this.Do appropriate changes as per your HTML structure.

```js
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) {
  element.find('tr').attr('r-params','resourceId=10); 
}
```

Comment: OP wants to add to time slots, not events. Read the question more carefully

Comment: Also, the question is about v4.. Whereas this code is for previous versions. New version has only parameter for eventRender